# Creating a Religion - Against Christianity-esque and Islam-esque religions to establish a pantheon of false(nonexistent) gods

Tags: technology, magic, religion, gods

To begin with the gods of both Islam-esque and Christianity-esque in my story are just super humanoid beings with semi-immortality(They won't die but can be killed) but they already died including all their offsprings that would have taken their place. All thats left are their super advance technologies(The 'gods' were in fact the last 2 of their super advanced civilization).

Come 500 years after they died the religion that they established is still going strong with Crusades and Jihads dividing the world in half. The world has magic(a mutation from the god like humanoid beings)

The good thing about the crusades and jihad is that because the whole world is split in two and its might makes right rule in most areas, the roads are fully developed, there are industries capable of of supporting the armies of both sides on a massive scale. But also the population is always culled due to the crusades and jihad so suffering and poverty in most war torn places runs rampant but the inner territories of both sides flourishes due to its distance from war zone. The difference between the rich and poor is so large that the fear of rebellion can be realize once the crusades and jihad ends

Now you come to the story as someone from modern day earth and see the world divided in to two, just that this world is ripe of strife and suffering. Being the good person you are, you want to put a stop to it. The only probable way to do it is to create a religion to false gods. Upon stumbling on their hidden cache of technologies you are only able to use 3 things atm.

1. Time Space storage device in form of watch
2. Atomic re constructor device in form of a box which can be resized according to needs
3. Orbital Microwave satellite cannon

Using these 3 technologies, you should achieve the following

1. Stop the current crusade/jihad from advancing further
2. Cull extremists from both sides
3. Establish yourself as a prophet of a 'God of light' and establish a religion
4. Destroy the validity of both Christian-esque and Islam-esque religions not with overwhelming military/fire power but influence and if possible economics
5. Establish a pantheon of false(nonexistent) gods to denounce Christian-esque and Islam-esque further.
6. Destroy all scriptures of the 2 religions
7. Convert most(60%) of the population to your church, and you shall name it

"The Church of Violence"

you need to achieve all 7 before 50 years(Your probable time of death)

Your first course of action will be the total destruction of both crusading army and jihad army during a battle of massive proportions including all supplies, leaders and its support structure. This should buy you 1 to 5 years of free action anywhere in the continent to further your agenda and goals focusing mostly on the common and poor folk. From then onwards what would be the probable step to achieve the 7 objectives in 50 years time

The magic in this world are that what can normally be read on books or typical D&D game with more powerful magicians capable of destroying battalions of troops. Normally only magicians can beat magicians. 1 out of 50 people in this world are magicians. It is said that the magicians pulls of their magic from their belief, you on the other hand believe that it is not. YOu can expect little magicians joining your church however these magicians that you will breed will be a different kind one as you'll be able to teach them how does the world works.

Technology wise you can manufacture things that your are capable of thinking of, from simple clothing to flying ships(arks) of several kilometers long give if you have enough matter for the re constructor to use, with the atomic re constructor doing the hard work of production you should be able to at least shock and awe anyone you come across i mean you can raze cathedral down with your giant 'rod' of steel. Everything you produce you can store it on your time space watch. The hard part on the watch is that it doesn't tell time....

Not to mention your control over the orbital cannon is something that should be used wisely and strategically. It is not something you want to squander as you need to preserve the shock effect of firing it to your enemies. I mean you can turn a battlefield into a fiery wasteland in no time, any one survives that or sees that will be sure to be awed and scared of you and certainly will follow you ot of fear. YOu can even make nobles grovel down to you just to prevent you from firing at their territory. You destroying an army is enough to ensure of the compliance of any one who is able to see your deeds.

Also you must remember, you're the weakest human in that world. YOu dont have magic, you dont have the ability nor the capacity to survive in such landscape, you'll use your technology on hand to achieve the goals, but the paramount of all your goals require you to have the most powerful influence or at least someone of influence that is capable to swaying masses.

And also your church doesn't shy away from violence.

Comment: "The world has magic" - what kind of magic? How common is it? How powerful is it? Would an orbital cannon completely decimating a town be viewed as something special, or would they think you figured out a spell nobody knew, or would they shrug and say "I could've done that." You should also go into more detail about the technologies - what exactly do they do, what are their limitations, etc.

Comment: @RobWatts thx... writing that now

Comment: What does an atomic re constructor do other than be resized?

Comment: `Being the good person you are, you want to put a stop to it. The only probable way to do it is to create a religion to false gods.` In a world divided into two **very** devout religions, creating a new, false one is probably not the best - or the only - solution.

Comment: @RobWatts since *decimate* means kill every 10th soldier and is a rather precise thing, how does “completely” doing it affect its meaning?

Comment: The actual question here is quite disguised (unclear), and it finding a solution to cover all 7 steps outlined to solve the problem seems very, very broad.

Comment: What do you mean by destroy all the scriptures?

Comment: So essentially kill off all Abrahamic religions?

Comment: I just want to point out that both those religions believe in one god and many would argue they worship the same god. Both believe that their one god was the god of Abraham Isaac and Jacob, spoken of in the Old Testament and the Torah. The only difference is that Islam believes that those books have been corrupted and the Qu'ran has brought the truth about them through divine revelation. [See here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_view_of_the_Christian_Bible)

Comment: Please, please don't use real religions if you can avoid it. It turns out good only rarely, and unless you already are a published author with good reviews, it can easy keep you from publishing. Also, I don't quite get what would you want us to answer.

Comment: If you want to know how to make a religion -- go study Scientology and Heinlein's "Stranger in a Strange Land". L.Ron Hubbard and Heinlein were friends so there's a chicken/egg question in there for me...

Answer (score 4):

### Use [Sikhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikhism) for ideas for your religion

The reason for this is because it has fundamental ideals that are based around equality for all, which will be a major appeal to those in poverty in your world.  Also the history of Sikhism has several parallels to what is happening in your world and what you are trying to accomplish:

- It was formed in a place that was dominated by two religions: Islam and Hinduism.
- They have had social/political goals like the ones you are trying to accomplish
- They formed their own military
- They ran into all kinds of obstacles and opposition that your story would run into (like their leaders being assassinated)

#### Extremism

Extremists in the Christian and Muslim groups in your world will be easy to cull but very hard to stop.  It is very difficult to kill an ideology and if you look at modern day terrorism you will see that no matter how many have been killed more keep joining them.

The bigger danger is if/when these people join your cause.  They will change your religion to fit their extremist views rather than let the religion change their views.  You will have to engineer your religion to be as resistant to these attempts as possible, which is easier said than done.

#### Destroying scriptures

This is a **very bad idea**.  If you attempt to destroy all the scripture of a different religion it will cause the reverse to happen.  People will actively attempt to protect it and read it to find out why you are so hell bent on destroying it.  What is in these books that you are so scared of that you want them destroyed?

The better choice is to handle it how groups have handled it in real life by integrating their religious texts into your own.   If they do not fit well with your religion's beliefs make slight edits and newer revisions based on new divine revelations and research of historic documents.  Use obscure verses and passages in them that point to your religion as the next chapter of their religion.

#### Converting 60% of the world

Not happening in 50 years even with your advance technology.  Ideas take time to spread in eras without the Internet.  Also it can take several generations for a new religion to take root in a new area.  Older people can be rather stubborn on things like this, after all you are essentially trying convince them that everything they spent their whole life believing and pursuing was wrong.

Also diminishing returns kick in.  There are those who cling to their beliefs no matter what and influence their children to follow their same views.  If you look at our [world's religious numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_populations) Christianity and Islam combined is less than 55% and they both have had over a thousand years to spread.

Even having all the advance tech on your side will not make it happen because of how faith works.  Faith in a religion cannot be cemented by signs and wonders no matter how grand they are, humans simply do not work that way.

For example, lets say I had been divinely blessed and could bring anyone who recently died back from the grave by touching them (lets say 3 day limit, and they are fully healed from whatever caused their death).  Then there was a school shooting where many people died, national media is covering it, and so I walk on to the scene and proceed to raise all the victims back from the dead.  I then use the media's coverage to tell the world of my new religion.  Many people will initially claim to believe, but as time passes and that event becomes nothing more than a crazy memory, will they still believe?  They will end up believing in the signs and wonders not the religion.